# Find first N entries in directory using only find

Tags: find, sh

Is it possible to select just N files using only the find(1) command?

```
find /var/lib/inbox \
    -type f
    -WHAT? 10
    -execdir mv --target-directory=/var/tmp/scratch/ '{}' +
```

I read the man page, but can't find anything obvious. Of course, this can be easily solved using a pipe and head:

```
find /var/lib/inbox -type f | head | xargs mv -t /var/tmp/scratch
```

Comment: why don't you want the pipe approach?

Comment: The pipe's fine. Just wanted to know if there existed an option I didn't know about.